# Android: Height of visible Screen - dp .... working solutions?

Tags: android, size, screen, scrollview, metrics

I saw this question was asked 100 times ... but none of the solutions i tried is working... the most are working on 2 of 3 devices, and on the third the rendering is wrong :(

I need the size of the visible Screen reduced by my "button_area" at the bottom (see the ic_launcher icon, for example 40dp height) to give the size to my WebView.

(All because i want it bring to work that i have a scrollable WebView, and when i touch the button_area i can scroll the complete screen up to show a menu below the button_area with ScrollView)

I tried about 10-15 solutions i found on the web, sometimes it´s working on the emulator and on my little samsung galaxy ace, but on the galaxy S3 the height is wrong again. Tried different ways and codes...

My Screen should look like this:

[image: Screen should look like this]

Actually my code looks like this:

```
    // STATUSBAR
    int statusbar = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
           statusbar = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      }   
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Statusbar= " + String.valueOf(statusbar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

    // GET SCREEN-HEIGHT
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // HEIGHT IN PIXEL
    float pix_h = metrics.heightPixels;

    // HEIGHT IN DP
    float dp_h = (metrics.heightPixels * 160) / metrics.ydpi;
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Height in DP= " + String.valueOf(dp_h), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int pixels = (int) ((dp_h) * scale + 0.5f);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Height in Pixel= " + String.valueOf(pixels), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int height = pixels - statusbar;
```

Thx for your help!

Best Regards
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getMeasuredWidth();` and `getMeasuredHeight()`? If you need to get the screen size before the layout you must use a dummy activity, for example one that extends this class:

```
public class MeasureLayout extends RelativeLayout {

private static int windowH, windowW;

public MeasureLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MeasureLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}


protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    windowW = getMeasuredWidth();
    windowH = getMeasuredHeight();
}

public static int getWidth(){
    return windowW;
}

public static int getHeight(){
    return windowH;
}
```

}

otherwise the values will be 0.

Hope this helps, Alex

Comment: ok, i´ll try it tomorrow (it´s 11pm here) ... second problem: i´m very new to android/java, but i´ll try it ;) ... i have some activities with different layouts before this activity gets called, should i try to measure the height in one of this activities and store the height? So it should be possible to have the height available in my onCreate, right?

Comment: this is exactly the purpose of the dummy activity I posted: you run it , for example, as your main activity and you can access the values from the other activities too, since they are stored as static variables in MeasureLayout.